# Java: using methods of other classes

Tags: java, class, methods

I am developing a project in java. I have a MainFrame, in this MainFrame I have some MyJPanel classes, and in Panels I have some MyJToggleButton classes.

Now, I am confused in some point. I would like to do this;
When a MyJToggleButton is pressed,other MyJToggleButtons in other MyJPanels shell be selected.

Generally I have this kind of problems. In MyJPanel, I don't have the other panel's buttons nor methods.

I hope I could explain my problem,
Thanks for your help

Comment: MVC is what you are looking for ("Model - View - Controller") - just google it.

Comment: OP wants to select buttons, not divide the project in layers!!!

Comment: if you want to get an answer, please, share your code (and images if necessary) and explain exactly the problem you face.... also explain better what you mean with **select**... If you have buttons `a` and `b` you want to execute `b` actions when `a` is pressed?

Comment: Yeah excatly MVC is what I want. I need to know more. I read a little but some examples would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You describe something like this:

```
MainFrame
  |
  |_ MyJPanel.class
  |    |
  |    |_MyJToggleButton
  |
  |_otherMyPanel.class
       |
       |_otherMyJToggleButton
```

These are all View-Classes that represent some data to the user. If you want to add functionality you should write them in a controller. And your Business-Logic in a Model. You should read about [MVC-Pattern](http://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you represent the same thing with MyJToggleButtons.

What I may advice is to use MVC design pattern. You split your application to the Model part and View part. Controller part then listens to View and/or Model and every time change occurs in Model/View things are updated. Especially if you represent something in GUI in different places, both places would get a message from a Controller to be updated, because model changed.

Comment: actually SO is not a place for opinions... is about concrete programmatic problems

Comment: There was a question and I gave solution, that I think is good enough. Maybe other programmers can have different solutions to the problem. That's why I added, that this is my opinion. Of course I could provide a source code with solution, but It's not a homework task. Sorry if I made something wrong